# PostgreSQL exported csv file could not be read in ms Sql Server database

Tags: postgresql, sql-server-2005

A csv file was exported from PostgreSQL database, but the exported file could not be imported into SQL Server, but same csv was easily imported into PostgreSQL.

Query to export was:

```
copy(select * from tablename where columnname = 'z') to '/path'
```

Comment: That does not produce a csv file.  It is producing what PostgreSQL calls a text formatted file.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, that statement does not create a CSV file. The correct syntax is:

```
copy(select * from tablename where columnname = 'z') to '/path/file_name.csv' delimiter ',' csv header;
```

A brief description of the options is below. See the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html) for more details.

- DELIMITER - indicates the character separator to use. Default is tab for CSV
- CSV - indicates CSV format
- HEADER - the file should contain the header line with the column names